# Accidental changed from Ubuntu 16.04 to ElementaryOS

Tags: apt, software-sources

My Ubuntu distro (16.04) now thinks its ElementaryOS. I wanted to try out the Pantheon  desktop, so I installed it, however now when I run lsb_release -a I get the following

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 0.4 Loki
Release:    0.4
Codename:   loki
```

Been reviewing my /etc/apt/sources.list and was missing "main" so I added it, but it didn't help

```
 # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)]/ wily main restricted

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial restricted main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial restricted main universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates restricted main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates restricted main universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports restricted multiverse main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports restricted multiverse main universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security restricted main universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security restricted main universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I would try `ppa-purge` against the PPA you added to install Pantheon. Of course, it will remove it.

Comment: You might just want to reinstall `lsb-release` from the Ubuntu repositories: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lsb-release`.

Comment: I manually removed the PPA, and it wont let me reinstall lsb-release, get the following error:
Reinstallation of lsb-release is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.